# PHP Function Organization

Tags: php, module, organization, code-organization

I am writing a pretty basic php app and have created a pretty big mess of functions to do various things, e.g. display_user_nav(), display_user_list() etc. I want a way to organize these in a logical way. What I really need is something like a ruby module, but I haven't been able to find a php equivalent. I also feel that from a programming standpoint they don't belong in classes, as I already have a User object to contain information for one user, and don't want to have to create and store a new object whenever I want to use them.

What I am doing now:

```
display_user_table()
display_user_edit_form()
```

What I kind of want to be able to do (sort of like Ruby):

```
User_Functions::Display::Table()
User_Functions::Display::Edit_Form()
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.3+, you have [namespaces](http://php.net/namespaces) available.

So you can name your functions (the namespace separator is `\`):

```
User_Functions\Display\Table
User_Functions\Display\Edit_Form
```

However, it seems like using a class for this wouldn't be a bad idea. If you feel that display functions don't really belong to `User` (the same way many people think serialization methods don't make sense in the target objects), you can create a class like this:

```
class DisplayUser {
    private $user;
    function __construct(User $u) { $this->user = $u; }
    function table() { /* ... */ } 
    function displayForm() { /* ... */ } 
}
```

Comment: thanks. I am pretty amateur with php, so I didn't really know how to implement namespaces. This is just what I was looking for. I also understand that I should ideally be using a more MVC-like structure to keep things organized, but frankly the project is small enough that is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

how about Abstract Classes!? or singletons? thats a good way to organize your code

Answer (score 0):

Well you could break them out into helper classes for example:

```
$helper = new UserHelper();
$helper->renderTable($user);
$helper->renderForm($user, 'edit');
```

The architecture of the helpers could be more complexx and implement a fluid interface or something to that effect depending on how your classes operate.

Another approach might be to attach decorators to your objects to perform these functions.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be such functions at all but a template that takes care of all HTML output.

The problem is you are using functions in a wrong way: make a function only to repeat some operations more than once.
Do not use a function for just single operation.